# How can i increase the max video length on a LG G4?

Tags: android, video, android-camera, smartphone

The LG G4 has a max video length of 5 mins at 4k. I want to use it to shoot footage for my youtube channel, but 5 mins at a time is not helpful. I haven't purchased it yet so I'm wondering if you guys have tried getting longer videos. Is this a software limitation? Is it to keep cpu temps low? Will a different camera app solve the issue?

I'm not worried about the fat32 size limit because ntfs, hfs, etc are recognized by android with mods.

Comment: StackOverflow is for questions directly related to programming, I'd suggest asking your question here: https://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

4k video quality occupies lots of space because it is full HD maybe your device does't have enough space to record long video.
Try to reduce the quality, once you reduce the quality your device will show how long you can record a video or increase the space of your device or in your memory card.